# Javascript clicks suddenly completely stopped working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been working on a project and have iterations of it (ensuring that each worked with its intended functionality before moving on).

As I went to start working today, a key part of my functionality has stopped working; even worse, opening up previous iterations (which have NOT been modified) also do not work for this feature.

I have not edited the code whatsoever.

The relevant code is here:

```
window.onload = function(){ // test for clicks on list
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  ul.onclick = function(event){
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

and the function getEventTarget

```
function getEventTarget(e){
e = e || window.event;
return e.target || e.srcElement;
}
```

It is not doing anything with the click event (not producing any console logs). As I reiterate, it was working perfectly fine prior to now.

I have restarted my computer, completely cleared the browsers history (Chrome), tried the code on another computer (which it also was previously working on, to no avail), and tried different browsers.

What do I do?

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<div class="mylist hidden">
<div class="container">

<div id="addplaylist"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>
  <span>Here's my List</span>
</a></div>
<br />

<ul id="list">
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: has your HTML changed?

Comment: I mean this with all sincerity, but have you checked your Internet connection?

Comment: My HTML has not changed whatsoever. And yes, MadGab, my internet connection is working fine.

Comment: please post up your HTML just to check, because I just tested your code in the snippet editor with a list with the correct ID and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: @Jhecht the id 'list' is dynamically generated from the javascript, and that is working fine. The click events through the onload() event aren't working.

Comment: without the HTML we're only looking at half the picture. 90% of the time for me when the javascript doesn't work its because i fudged the HTML accidentally somewhere.

Comment: @Jhecht added HTML to op.

Comment: your list is empty. add an element to it and click on it.

Comment: @Jhecht As previously stated, when my JS loads the list is populated. This worked before.

Comment: then what is the HTML _after_ your Javascript loads the HTML? Because it worked just fine once I added an `<li>` element to it.

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, I add <li> elements with some other tags inside that <ul id="list"> tag. It should work fine, because it did before! However, it is not working right now!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135479/discussion-between-jhecht-and-helpisgood).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add atleast a single text inside ul tag. Then only you will be able to click it.

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   document.getElementById("list").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     var target = getEventTarget(event);
   });
 });
```

Comment: This answer is useless. It's functionality equivalent to OPs code.

Comment: Both are different

Comment: No it's not different. Inline event handlers and using `addEventListener` do exactly the same thing. Here `.onclick` and `.addEventListener('click',` along with `window.addEventListener('load'` and `window.onload` do the same thing.

Comment: Inline event have a limit. But addEventalistener not

Comment: The code is still the same and doesn't work to solve OP's issue.